# CertificateRequest.CreateSigningRequest() - Where is the private key?

Tags: vb.net, rsa, private-key, csr

I'm trying to create a simpleish single-form VB.Net app that creates Certificate Signing Requests (CSRs) for signing by Cert Authority (CA), and subsequent use on domain websites.

I've managed to get *that* much working, and the CA likes the CSRs my app creates (they parse as valid).

BUT, I don't seem to have the private key, rendering the signed certificate useless to me.

My code, reduced to the relevant bits:

```
Dim Subject As String = $"CN={CN},OU={OU},O={O},L={L},ST={ST},C={C}"
Dim MyRSA As RSA = RSA.Create(iKeyLen)
Dim CrtReq As New CertificateRequest(Subject, MyRSA, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1)

' ...Bunch of stuff to get bSanPayload...

CrtReq.CertificateExtensions.Add(New X509Extension("Subject Alternative Name", bSanPayload, True))

Dim CSR() As Byte = CrtReq.CreateSigningRequest()
Dim B64 As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(CSR)

' ...then take B64, format in columns, add CSR header and footer, etc...
```

Thing is, even though I can get a valid, CA-signed certificate after doing this, the associated private key is... nowhere. I feel like I should be setting up the RSA differently, but to borrow the expression, I don't know what I don't know. MS's article on `CreateSigningRequest()` doesn't say anything about placing an unsigned copy in "Certificate Enrollment Requests," or how to match up the signed certificate to a private key.

How do I set this up correctly, so that I have the private key available for certificate installation and use?